# How to send data from PostgreSQL to Android via PHP?

Tags: php, android, postgresql

I'm working on an Android application that includes communication (up- and download) with a PostgreSQL database. I want to retrieve data from the database using a PHP script.

The table name is "table" and its columns are "id", "username" and "title".

In a very simple case (one single entry in the table), this works for me:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$result = $statement->execute();
$fetched= $statement->fetch();

$echo = array();

array_push($echo,array(
   "id"=>$fetched['id'],
   "username"=>$fetched['username'],
   "title"=>$fetched['title']
));

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$echo);
```

Data reception in Android works with a

```
JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(response);
```

and I can read the data as a JSON Object.

However, I'm also having the case where I need to get more than one entry from the table. I read a lot of tutorials, but all of them have different approaches. I tried the following:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$result = $statement->execute();
$fetched= $statement->fetch();

$echo = array();

while ($row = $fetched) {
  $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
  $row_array['username'] = $row['username'];
  $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];

array_push($echo, $row_array);
}

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$echo);
```

But this way always returns null. To be honest, I also don't understand exactly what the role of $row is in that case.

Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Edit: I'm getting a null result means that I'm getting a NullPointerException once I try to access the return value from the input stream in Android Studio for the first time.
The error looks like this:

```
08-26 17:17:16.605 5278-5278 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                           java.lang.NullPointerException
                                               at com.example.sainz.example.RandomActivity$1LoginAsync.onPostExecute(RandomActivity.java:101)
                                               at com.example.sainz.example.RandomActivity$1LoginAsync.onPostExecute(RandomActivity.java:40)
                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: RTFM [fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php): `Fetches a row from a result set associated with a PDOStatement object.` A **ROW** of data. one single solitary row, not the entire result set. `while ($row = $result->fetch())` would get you all the rows, sequentially.

Comment: Hmm that is true, thanks for the hint. But it should still return the first line of data and not null, right? I changed the code to what you recommend, but the return value is still null.

Comment: which return value. your encoded array looks like `{"result":null}`? or you get no json at all?

Comment: I get a NullPointerException the first time I try to access the input stream results. First I was unsure if the error is maybe in the Android java part, but as the first version that only gets the first line of data works, that's unlikely. I added the error message to the initial post.

Comment: Hey there. I dug a bit deeper and I'm about to believe that it's indeed an issue of the Android code. I'm performing the request to the php server in an asynchronous task. In my doInBackground method, an InputStream is created that apparently causes issues. I found several topics on that. Could somebody confirm that there might be a connection between the size of the received json object and the inputStream not being loaded correctly? Considering it's asynchronous, there might be something to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are calling [`fetch` method](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) only once, instead of calling it in a loop (one fetch for each row), as:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, username, title FROM table");
$statement->execute();

$echo = array();

while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
  $row_array = array();
  $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
  $row_array['username'] = $row['username'];
  $row_array['title'] = $row['title'];

  array_push($echo, $row_array);
}
$statement = null;

echo json_encode(array("result"=>$echo);
```

Another option is to use [`fetchAll` method](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), probably using `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`, and have the `$echo` array object done at once.

Comment: Thanks a lot. $result->fetch() causes an exception whereas $statement->fetch() allows to return what I need. That's an answer that helped me proceed.